# Real Analysis, related to Arzela-Ascoli theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Arzela Ascoli theorem: For a sequence of functions 
$\{f_{n}\}_{\mathbb{N}}$ defined over an interval [a,b] which are bounded and equicontinuous
there exists a subsequence $\{f_{n_{k}}\}$which converges uniformly.

Now consider two sequence of functions $\{f_{n}\}_{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\{g_{n}\}_{\mathbb{N}}$, with $f_{n}:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g_{n}:[c,d]\rightarrow [a,b]$. Both these sequence of functions are uniformly bounded and are equicontinuous.
Let $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_{n} =f$  and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} g_{n} =g$.

Define a composite function $h_{n}:[c,d]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $h_{n}=f_{n}\circ g_{n}$.

When is the following true

1. $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} h_{n} = f\circ g$
2. Due to the conditions of uniform boundedness and equicontinuity on $f_{n}$ and $g_{n}$, will $h_{n}$ also be uniformly bounded and equicontinuous ?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1) Show that $g_n$ converges uniformly to $g$.

2)
since $f_n$ are equicontinuous on a compact interval, they are uniformly equicontinuous.